# I want to split elements within a nested list by comma

Tags: python, python-3.x

Below is the list.

```
List=[['hello', 'how'], ['are', 'you', 'hope'], ['you,are,fine', 'thank', 'you']]
```

I want the output list as

```
List=[['hello', 'how'], ['are', 'you', 'hope'], ['you', 'are' ,'fine', 'thank', 'you']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a simple iteration and `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
lst=[['hello', 'how'], ['are', 'you', 'hope'], ['you,are,fine', 'thank', 'you']]
result = []
for i in lst:
    temp = []
    for j in i:
        temp += j.split(",")
    result.append(temp)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[['hello', 'how'],
 ['are', 'you', 'hope'],
 ['you', 'are', 'fine', 'thank', 'you']]
```

Comment: Could you please help me solve one more issue. How to replace the comma symbol with white space in ['you,are,fine'] and get the same nested list format.

Comment: `result = [[j.replace(",", " ") for j in i] for i in lst]` ?

Answer (score 4):

Try the following nested [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) that recompiles the list in a single walk-through while [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)ting the tokens:

```
>>> [[token for el in sub for token in el.split(',')] for sub in List]
[['hello', 'how'], ['are', 'you', 'hope'], ['you', 'are', 'fine', 'thank', 'you']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
[[z for z in x.split(',') for x in y] for y in List]
```